# Javascript Window Event Before Request URL Reach Web Server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, browser

Is there any window event we could trap before the request reach the web server?

So, if I have page with url: `http://localhost/Test.aspx`, then when I request this page in the URL through browser address, somehow the window browser would detect this and run javascript do to something then afterwards would continue the request to the web server. So the flow like:

> Request URL -> Intercept by Window Event and do Something with
>   Javascript -> Request reach Web Server.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to create a browser plugin or what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to modify some values in the cookies before the request reach web server. No, I am not trying to create a browser plugin.

Comment: OK, but if you don't want to create a plugin, then the only other way for you to run JavaScript code is loading a page. And at the moment the code is executed, the request was already sent (because the code is part of the response). So I think you have to provide more information about your case, otherwise the answer is: It's not possible.

Comment: Basically, what I want to try to achieve is to modify the cookies value before the request reach web server, so that in the web server, the updated cookies value would be able to be used in the web server.

Comment: I already understood that from your previous comment. Maybe you are just not aware of how HTTP and JavaScript works. The sequence is `request -> response -> execute JavaScript`. I.e. the JavaScript code is only executed *after* the response was received (because it is part of the response), at which point it is too late to manipulate the request.

Comment: You may do that, if the user is on a page of you all ready, and move to a second one. There, when is click to see the second page, you run  you javascript before leaving the page, and after that the second page is load...

Comment: Yes, it's possible to be that way. But what if, the page is accessed directly by typing it in the URL?